# How to run a ant build file before running the Android Applicaiton using Launch group in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I am trying to create new  Launch Group in eclipse "Run Configurations" and run a ant build file and an android application together.I added my custom ant build file in the new Launch group configuration .When i try to run this, I am getting the following error

Variable references non-existent resource : ${build_project:/build.xml}

What should i do to resolve this ?

Comment: try this one `./android update project -p /root path of your android  project` this will create one ant file for you and then run `ant release`

Comment: @nilkash: ant file is already there with me . i need to run a target in that whenever user tries to launch the android application . i thought launch group will help me do the same .

Comment: you want to run your application on device right?

Comment: emulator or device..anything is fine, but i need to run this ant target just before the launch of the application .

Comment: you can directly use run option in eclipse to run your application on device. why you want to use ant? Any specific reason?

Comment: yes, i want to run some tests, which will evaluate the setup before launching the application

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40414/discussion-between-abhi-and-nilkash)